# Use requests_html inside a flask application

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, flask, screen-scraping

I am trying to run the `html.render()` method from the Python module `requests_html` from a Flask application. However, whenever my application code calls that function, I get this error: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.`

Here is the function that uses the `html.render` module:

```
def extractor(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    found = soup.find_all("a", href=privacy_regex)
    if found:
        print("Using Default Web Scraping bs4+regex")
        found = [tag['href'] for tag in found]
        uri = sorted(found, key=rank_url)[-1]
        return urljoin(url, uri)
    else:
        print('Using HTML Rendering')
        r.html.render()
        links = r.html.absolute_links
        privacy_links = [x for x in links if privacy_regex.search(x)]
        uri = sorted(privacy_links, key=rank_url)[-1]
        return urljoin(url, uri)
```

And here is my application code

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def text_output():
        url = request.form['url_text']
        print(url)
        text, domain = url_input_parser(url)
        print(text, domain)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much!